# How to set a variable on node.js if it's name is in other variable?

Tags: variables, node.js

On the browser I can use the window object. How to do this on node.js?

```
var name="test"; 
var <name> = 3; 
print(test); 
//output: 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't do this in node in any local scope, but you can do this in global scope (like in browser window object):

```
var name = 'test';
global[name] = 3;
console.log(test); // 3
console.log(global['test']); // 3;
```

So, `global` object exactly the same as browser `window` object.

Difference is: in browser when you declaring `var test = 2` in top-level scope you actually creating `window['test']`, but in node you don't, because every module scoped with function call by default.